# VB.NET FTP Explorer

Tags: vb.net, ftp, explorer, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

I try this source and video but on connect to ftp i get error on connecting.

Source:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net


Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtServer.Select()
    End Sub

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    tvServer.Nodes.Item(0).Collapse()
    LoadFTPRemote(txtServer.Text, tvServer)
End Sub

Public Sub LoadFTPRemote(ByVal dirpath As String, eTree As TreeView)
    eTree.Nodes.Item(0).Nodes.Clear()
    eTree.BeginUpdate()
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(dirpath), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
    Do While reader.Peek() >= 0
        Dim nD As TreeNode = New TreeNode(reader.ReadLine())
        eTree.Nodes.Item(0).Nodes.Add(nD)
    Loop
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
    eTree.Nodes.Item(0).Expand()
    eTree.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Private Sub tvServer_AfterExpand(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvServer.AfterExpand
    tvServer.BeginUpdate()
    Dim Node As TreeNode = e.Node
    For Each CNode As TreeNode In Node.Nodes
        Dim PathBuilder As String = txtServer.Text & ProperRemoteLink(CNode.FullPath)
        If Not Path.HasExtension(PathBuilder) Then
            CNode.Nodes.Clear()
            Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(PathBuilder), FtpWebRequest)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
            Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
            Dim strList As New List(Of String)
            Do While reader.Peek() >= 0
                Dim xNod As TreeNode = New TreeNode(IO.Path.GetFileName(reader.ReadLine()))
                CNode.Nodes.Add(xNod)
            Loop
            reader.Close()
            response.Close()
        End If
    Next
    tvServer.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Public Function ProperRemoteLink(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim output As String = input
    If input.StartsWith("FTP Server") Then output = input.ToString.Remove(0, 10)
    Return output
End Function

Private Sub tvServer_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvServer.AfterSelect
    lblStatus.Text = txtServer.Text & ProperRemoteLink(e.Node.FullPath)
End Sub
```

End Class

error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
> Parameter name: index
> at System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at zbmsdn.MainForm.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\javad\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\zbmsdn\zbmsdn\MainForm.vb:line 11
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)

Comment: The  tells you that the `index` parameter was outside of the valid range and exactly where it happened. It should be obvious that the very first thing to do is to find out what value was used for `index` and what the valid range was.  VS has a debugger for a reason.    Use it.  Even if you don't know how to use breakpoints, etc, the IDE still provides you with plenty of information when an exception is thrown.  Don't ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try check if a node is selected before doing (0)...

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If tvServer.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
        tvServer.Nodes.Item(0).Collapse()
        LoadFTPRemote(txtServer.Text, tvServer)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is what I think the problem is, but then again your code you've given is very limited.